# (Dart) Widget isn't a type

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

So, I am trying to put multiple objects into a body for which I used Dart's `Stack` function. While doing that I am getting this error. I am new to Dart and I am still learning about it's data types.

I have two questions mainly -

1. What are the data types that I can put inside the `Stack` function?
2. Is this an efficient way in Dart to add multiple objects in a `body:`?

For your reference I am attaching a code below -

```
body: Stack(
      children: [Align(
        alignment: Alignment(0, 0),
        child: Text('Test?',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 28.0,
          color: Colors.black87,
          letterSpacing: 1.0,
          fontFamily: 'Quicksand',
          ),//TextStle
        ),//Text
      ),//Align

        Column(
          children: <widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              color: Colors.cyan,
              child: Text('What\'s up')
            ),//Container
          ],//<Widget>
        ),//Column
      ]
  ),



Error: 'widget' isn't a type.
          children: <widget>[
                     ^^^^^^
```

Comment: widget? It need to be _Widget_

Answer (score 0):

Try it without the `<widget>`

```
Column(
          children:[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              color: Colors.cyan,
              child: Text('What\'s up')
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

more information about stack function - https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html

Answer (score 0):

Try below code just remove  in column refer Stack widget [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html)

```
 Stack(children: [
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment(0, 0),
                child: Text(
                  'Test?',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 28.0,
                    color: Colors.black87,
                    letterSpacing: 1.0,
                    fontFamily: 'Quicksand',
                  ), //TextStle
                ), //Text
              ), //Align

              Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      color: Colors.cyan,
                      child: Text('What\'s up')), //Container
                ], //<Widget>
              ), //Column
            ]),
```

Result of your screen:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Stack is not a function, it creates a stack layout of widgets[means bind with a lot of children].
2. The list literal type 'List' isn't of expected type 'List'. The list's type can be changed with an explicit generic type argument or by changing the element types.

you need not define it as a widget. Remove `<widget>`

```
Stack(children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment(0, 0),
            child: Text(
              'Test?',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 28.0,
                color: Colors.black87,
                letterSpacing: 1.0,
                fontFamily: 'Quicksand',
              ), //TextStle
            ), //Text
          ), //Align

          Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  color: Colors.cyan,
                  child: Text('What\'s up')), //Container
            ], //<Widget>
          ), //Column
        ])
```

Answer (score 0):

1. in Stack you should put widgets. or a function that returns a widget. the data type here is a widget.
2. for the body you have to add the widget to or a function that returns a widget. so the efficient way to add multiple items to the body is to use widgets that are able to take multiple children such as `stack`, `column`